# Allocating twice - c++

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

I saw a lot of **similar** questions about deleting twice, but what happens when you allocating twice and delete only once? isn't the old version is still exist and how does the program compile?
Don't I have to kind of release the new one too, because according to the d'tor it gets called only once.[image: something like this]

For example:

```
    int main()
{ 

    int *ptr = new int;
    *ptr=5;
    ptr=new int; //again, different memory location
    *ptr=25;
    delete ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

what with the 5?? it will be a memory leak or something?

Comment: yes, it will get leaked. Compilation does not check for memory leaks. The code is valid.

Comment: ok, how can i ignore this memory leak? and why the compiler warn anything for me?

Comment: The best approach is to never use the `new` keyword. Modern `c++` has better ways to allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: What do you mean ignore? Compiler cannot warn you since detecting leaks is undecideable problem. But valgrind can check for leaks while running your program.

Comment: ***and why the compiler warn anything for me?*** It's not an easy for your compiler to detect. It may be able to detect simple leaks but if it can't detect all leaks it will give you a false sense of security.

Comment: There's very little that C++ will do for you to find bugs in your code, on its own. C++, famously, gives you every opportunity to screw up, and it is your responsibility to write code that correctly manages memory. Fortunately, in modern C++, proper use of containers and algorithms pretty much eliminates the need to allocate and deallocate anything yourself. Modern C++ code rarely uses `new` or `delete`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what with the 5?? it will be a memory leak or something?

Yes! The second `new` will overwrite `ptr`, and you will need the old address for deleting the first allocation. Unless you save `ptr` it in another variable, or delete it before the second `new`, or use another variable name for the second pointer, you will have no way of knowing the address of the first memory block, and you will not be able to free it. That is a memory leak.

By the way, welcome to SO

Answer (score 2):

> code.cpp:

```
int main()
{ 

    int *ptr = new int;
    *ptr=5;
    ptr=new int; //again, different memory location
    *ptr=25;
    delete ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code cause memory leak allocated by first new.

> compile the code like:

```
g++ -fsanitize=leak code.cpp -o code
./code
```

> output (ubuntu budgie x64):

```
=================================================================
==15281==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 4 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fa9f020e3d1 in operator new(unsigned long) (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsan.so.0+0x103d1)
    #1 0x5555ec6d217e in main (/home/srilakshmikanthanp/Documents/test/code+0x117e)
    #2 0x7fa9f00330b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)

SUMMARY: LeakSanitizer: 4 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, there will be a memory leak, even this doing something like this where you are losing the pointer address will cause a leak:

```
myPointer = new int;
myPointer = NULL; //leaked memory, no pointer to above int
delete myPointer; //no point at all
```

Notice that we can use delete on NULL it just won't do anything.

You can check out : [Smart Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) Which handle those things for you with a little overhead.

Comment: `NULL` is discouraged in C++. Use `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

After you have reassigned the `ptr` with the address of another object

```
ptr = new int; //again, different memory location
```

you no longer have an access to the first object and its address.
You won't be able to delete it. And that's a memory leak!

Answer (score 0):

You could think of this in terms of online shopping. When you call `new`, you place an order (for memory). When you call `delete`, you return the item (memory) for a refund. The goal is to end with what you started; everything should be returned for a refund.

If you return more than you order, the store will rightfully charge you with fraud (possible crash). This is the problem you read about in the other questions.

If you order more than you return, stuff (memory) accumulates in your home (process). This causes no problem for the store, as it is good for business. Authorities won't step in until your home overflows. However, you'll have problems as you try to navigate around the junk.